# ExtJS column data conversion

Tags: extjs

I am getting the data from REST API returning the data  and one of the column is   status of group and this is defined as integer in the database  and I want to do   convert it to string before display them in the UI. For example the status   return from REST API is 1 but I want to display as "Valid" ... But don't know   where the conversion will take place. Should I have the conversion **from int-  >string** in store or where Should I do this conversion. Please help.
Here is my model:

```
// Model
Ext.define('Console.model.Group', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [{
    name: 'id',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    name: 'group',
    type: 'string'
  }, { 
    name: 'state', 
    type: 'string'
  }],

  proxy: {
      type: 'rest',
      url: '/api/groups', // Joanne need to change the URL name here
      reader: 'json'
  }

});

// store
Ext.define('Console.store.Groups', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  model: 'Console.model.Group',
  autoSync: false,
  buffered: false,
  pageSize: 1000,
  autoLoad: false,
  autoDestory: true,
  purgePageCount: 3,
  sorters: [{
    property: 'label',
  }],
  trailingBufferZone: 100,

  proxy: {
    simpleSortMode: true,
      type: 'rest',
       url: '/api/groups',
       reader:  {
           type: 'json',
           root: 'data',
           totalProperty: 'total'
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: It depends. If you only ever intend to use it as a string and never want the int value, do it at the model level. If you want to just display it that way for the grid, use a column renderer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to want to use that mapping in more than one place then the most convenient thing to do is to do a mapping/conversion and create a virtual field right on your model:

```
       {
             name: 'statusText',
             mapping: 'status',
             convert: function(v, record) {
                    var map = {0:'Invalid', 1: 'Valid};
                    return map[v];
             }
        }
```